# Facebook Share Count not correct

Tags: facebook, api, count, share

can somebody please explain me why using [this query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=44515277971_10152906540372972%3Ffields%3Dshares&version=v2.3&) returns 7 as share count, even though this post has only one share. [Link](https://www.facebook.com/dasding/posts/10152906540372972).

I cant find an explanation of this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're comparing the shared posts count of the link with the shares of the post.

The Facebook website shows the `sharedposts` count of the link, and not the `shares` of the post.

Compare [SharedPosts](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=10152906540372972%2Fsharedposts&version=v2.3) to [shares](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=44515277971_10152906540372972&version=v2.3)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think im slowly getting a grasp of it. So the website shows the sharedposts-count. And not the shares... But can you explain me what exactly is the shares count then? Or the exact difference between those two (sharedposts / shares)